# Replacement drive for Lacie Network Space Max Raid 1

Tags: hard-drive, nas, raid-1

I have a faulty drive in my Lacie Network Space Max (Samsung HD103SI 1TB) [image: 1]

I have to install a replacement, but the original drive type seems to be out of production.

Can i replace it with this one? (WD RED WD10EFRX 1TB  )

[Newegg Link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236342)

I can't seem to find any official info on compatible drives. Only that the capacity of the drives should be matching

Comment: I would suggest that you contact the manufacturer support for clarification about compatible drives. You can add a different HDD in this situation but you should look for the same RPM and buffer size as well as for the same capacity. WD Red is a great NAS HDD but has different specifications from original HDD apart from the capacity so I don't think that it can offer the best compatibility in this case